# How do you include a whole body exercise in a body party split program?

Tags: bodyweight

I am a beginner who trains only bodyweight. I am in my first month of training, after training for half a year, I want to start doing a body part split as my main program. How do I include exercises like the 'Burpee', which targets several muscles. My main aim is to improve conditioning and strength.

So for example, here is a body split program.

Monday - Legs + Chest.

Wednesday - Back and biceps.

Friday - Triceps and abs.

How do I include burpees, which targets multiple muscles?

Comment: I think there's an underlying question we need to resolve first. Why do you think it's bad to include burpees on any of these days?

Comment: Due to being a low intensity whole body exercise, burpees are good as warm ups and cardiovascular exercises. If you used them in this way they could be used to warm up at the beginning of any or every workout, or as a part of a separate CV training day.

Comment: I dont want to use Burpees for any warm up. As I said before, the burpee is a whole body exercise. My program wont be a body split program, if I include many of these.

Comment: You're gonna get more benefits from including burpees on at least one of these days, than you will from excluding it entirely. Sure, a body split program is fine, but it's not supposed to be a hard rule to where you're not *allowed* to do anything that might engage the triceps on leg day.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to start doing a body part split as my main program. How do I include exercises like the 'Burpee', which targets several muscles.

By either:

1. Giving up on your desire to strictly group your exercises into one-body-part-per-workout days, or
2. Giving up on your desire to do exercises which target multiple body parts.

Comment: In the words of Alan Thrall, “have you tried caring less?”